# Sublime PHP method signature and description on autocomplete

Tags: php, autocomplete, sublimetext2, method-signature, sublimetext3

I really like sublime but I have 1 major issue stopping me from migrating from Netbeans:

I need sublime autocomplete to show function description and method signature (i'm working with Yii framework and I need to know exactly what each function does, returns and passed arguments types).

I tried installing several plugins but none worked...if there is such a way then i'm missing it.

Comment: Which plugins do you tried?

Comment: please see below the plugin i tried. i found this to work in JS but not PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just in time for [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-beta) !

> **Symbol Indexing.** Sublime Text now scans the files in your project, and builds an index of which files contain which symbols. This backs the new features Goto Definition and Goto Symbol in Project, both of which are available from the Goto menu. Goto Definition takes you to the definition of the symbol under the caret, while Goto Symbol in Project prompts you to select a symbol via fuzzy matching, and then takes you to the definition of that symbol.

Comment: @DannyValariola I thought you have a registered licence :-/

Comment: I will have...once i have the feature i need

Comment: This doesn't work on autocomplete tho. Sure, you can go to definition, but if you type Class:: and expect the autocomplete to only show definitions inside Class, that won't work (at least not here)

Answer (score 3):

you might want to try the code intel plugin

available [here](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel)

otherwise you could use zencoding see [here](http://urbangiraffe.com/2011/08/15/sublime-text-2-for-php/) for tips

alternatively alt + click should do it!

here's a relatively [new plugin](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-find-function-definition)

Comment: i tried almost every plugin available, also tried ZEN, INTEL, and much more....none does the trick

Comment: ctrl+r is for symbol search, keep in mind that i'm in Yii framework and not all method reside in the same file. Also there is no description, it's just goto